# Can 2 independent iPad apps communicate?

Tags: ios, ipad

A customer is talking to my boss about developing an iPad app. One of the items on the list is talking with another vendor's app on the iPad.

We could work out an API with the other vendor.  But is such communication even possible? I thought apps were pretty much sandboxed.  If it is possible, what is the technology / keyword / buzzword I need to study?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use URL scheme to open another app and to pass some information across, but you have no direct access to other apps as far as I know. Using API might be the option to pass more complicated data across.

Comment: check this out https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html

Comment: Thank you, Pancho and Vishnu.  I think those point me in the right direction.